# geode pdx date formats

Tags: gemfire, geode

I have a java.util.Date type stored in Geode region as a PdxInstance, in the format `Wed Sep 13 08:55:34 BST 2017` for example.

1. Is there a Pdx setting I am missing to format the date so I the date type includes milliseconds as well?
2. When I run a "get" on the region via the Geode REST API the date is returned as `mm/dd/yyyy` without the `hh:mm:ss` why is that? Is there a Jetty setting I can use to include the latter?

Thanks for comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JSONFormatter` class, used internally in Geode to handle REST requests/responses, supports only the format `MM/DD/YYYY` when handling dates, with no `HH:MM:SS`; while PDX supports all date fields, that's the reason why you see the difference in the output.
There's already a JIRA ticket created for this: [GEODE-226](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GEODE-226). You might want
to add yourself as a watcher to get updates about the progress.
Hope this helps.
Best regards.